# Kohana ORM insert/update a post() into db

Tags: php, kohana-3

I am new @Kohana and i am trying to put data into the dbase from a post.

```
$save = ORM::factory('Admin_test');
$save->users_id = $user->id;
etc
etc
etc
$save->save();
```

But how can i save the complete $this->request->post() at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out:

```
$save->values($this->request->post());
```